# child_process.spawn with parenthesis in arguments

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I have an imagemagick script that I need to use in node.  It works fine with the child_process.exec function.  I'm not sure exactly how to send it a stream to the exec command so I'm trying to use spawn.

This works fine.  No problems.

```
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var args = [
    '-',
    '-resize',
    '50%',
    './blank.png',
    '-composite',
    '-'
  ];
  var convert = spawn('convert', args);
```

Now the issue is I need to separate out the blank.png image and apply transformations to it.  No problem in Image Magick.  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis

So that starts to make it look something like this.

```
 convert image.jpg \
  \( blank.png -resize 50% \) -gravity center  -composite -composite output.jpg
```

I can't get that to work at all with spawn args in nodejs.
I've tried things like.

```
  var args = [
    '-',
    '\( ',
    './blank.png',
    '-resize',
    '50%',
    ' \),
    '-composite',
    '-'
  ];

  var args = [
    '-',
    '( ',
    './blank.png',
    '-resize',
    '50%',
    ' ),
    '-composite',
    '-'
  ];


   var args = [
    '-',
    '\( ./blank.png -resize 50% \)',
    '-composite',
    '-'
  ];
```

Nothing seems to work.  They all pass the wrong parameters to the function.  I just get convert errors.  Any ideas?

**Fixed**

```
 var args = [
    '-',
    '-resize',
    '100%',
    '(',
    './blank.png',
    '-resize',
    '50%',
    ')',
    '-composite',
    '-'
  ];
```

Comment: I don't *speak* node-ish, but the backslashes are there to protect the parentheses from being interpreted by the shell - is it possible that there is no shell involved here and you don't need them?

Comment: The problem is I need them to tell image magick to apply transformations just to the blank.png image and not the image that comes in from a stream.

Comment: And why does that prevent you from removing the backslashes?

Comment: Oh wow I got it now.  I didn't put a space in the parenthesis!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your "Fixed" example. My problem was trying to use the backslash escape in front of the parens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the escape character. Remember the '\' means something in Javascript strings too.

```js
 var args = [
    '-',
    '\\( ',
    './blank.png',
    '-resize',
    '50%',
    '\\)',
    '-composite',
    '-'
  ];
var convert = spawn('convert', args);
```